# Div expands past page height, but no scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have a div along the left side of my page for navigation links. Clicking on a header expands a subset of links. I have this div set to 100% of the page height so that the column takes up the entire left side of the page. The problem occurs when all of the sub categories are expanded. The content of the div runs off the bottom of the page, but doesn't add a scroll bar.

I tried setting the height to auto to see if that would fix the problem (ignoring the fact that it doesn't take up the whole left side), but that didn't fix it either.

So, what do I need to do to get a scroll bar when the div expands past the height of the page? Then have the scroll bar go away if it's not needed.

Thank you.

```
.leftNavigation {
display:block;
position:fixed;
width:200px;
height:100%;
top:140px;
left:0;
background-color:#f0f0f0;
```

}

```
<div class="leftNavigation">
    <p class="linkHeader" id="townLinksHeader"><img src="img/image.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Sunnyvale, CA" /></p>
    <div class="links" id="townLinks">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

There are 4 paragraph/div combinations inside the left navigation div. Only the paragraph is show until it is clicked on. The links div is then show. When each of those is expanded, it runs off the bottom of the page but doesn't add a scroll bar.

Adding overflow:auto didn't change anything.

Comment: Hard to say with out the code. Overflow: auto; usually does the trick.

Comment: Agree with @Jawad, it's actually impossible to say without the code, but my guess is someone's "clever" use of `overflow:hidden` somewhere on the main content or body/html containers.

Comment: Sorry, I just added code. Overflow:auto didn't do anything. I'm also not using overflow:hidden anywhere.

Comment: what happens when you set the height to auto? sounds like the left navigation is somehow getting `overflow: hidden`. you may need to wrap your navigation in another div with `height: 100%` while the inner div gets auto height. can you put the page someone where live or on jsfiddle

Comment: We really need to replicate the problem. With the above code, I can't. Guess I am not creative enough. Any possibility of the complete code with funcationality - http://jsfiddle.net/wMj6q/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the side content div use fixed positioning? Because, that is usually why a scrollbar does not appear. Try setting the `overflow:auto` css style on that div to add a scrollbar when needed.

**Update:**

You have top:140px in there and height:100%. This is actually pushing the side div down below the page. If the expandable content is not taking up much space, then it will flow off the bottom of the page and no scrollbar will appear.

Try this:

```
.leftNavigation {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top:140px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: To me it sounded like they want the browser to have a scrollbar, not the div itself.  `overflow:auto` shouldn't be necessary (or might be, depending on what tricks have been employed on the main layout).

Comment: Sorry, I added code. I just tried overflow:auto, but it didn't do anything. It didn't even add a scrollbar to the leftNavigation div.

Comment: Thank you very much. Leaving position:fixed didn't work, but I swapped it to relative and it worked great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When something is 'fixed' positioned, it will not add scroll bars. You can either try positioning it with `position: relative`, or you can set `top: 0`. If top:0 still isn't enough, you'll have to set the height to a fixed height that is smaller than your window.

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftNavigation {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top: 140px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

Now it's correct.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.